# Reverse Engineering Low Frequency Flat Field Correction

Tags: image-processing, lowpass-filter, reverse-engineering

I have feature in my camera that indicates "Low Frequency Flat Field correction" and I want to evaluate its impact on the image.

How can I do this?

Currently I can only take pictures of a uniform monochromatic light source.